# Trying to get ui.bootstrap dropdown to work

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a bootstrap dropdown working. I have attempted to pretty much exactly follow the code at [The Angular UI page](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown). It's not working.

I have a [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uYRI2yxd1tbjS550ddN2?p=preview).  Here's the code that's not working:

```
  <table>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" class="give-store-button-group dropdown">
          <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle="">{{backslaps[current].store}}</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li ng-repeat="store in backslaps">
              <a href>{{store.store}}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a container containing `dropdown` attribute directive.

```
<span class="dropdown" dropdown>
              <a href class="dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle="">{{backslaps[current].store}}</a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu"> .... </ul>
</span>
```

Check this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3o9iCuU8QwSfARli0A6B?p=preview)